# up to my satisfaction or to my satisfaction

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Which sentence is more correct?

1. My English is good but not to my satisfaction.
2. My English is good but not up to my satisfaction.

Or is there any other better way of saying the same thing?

And is this sentence correct "Is there any other better way of saying the same thing?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 1 is better than 2 however they both don't sound great.

"My English is okay, but it's not to the level that I desire." 
"My English is good, but it could be better."

I could see you saying, "My English is good, but my teacher is not satisfied"

Saying better combined with another doesn't work, I would say "Is there another way to say this?"

or "Is there a better way to say this?"

another is any + other.

or you could say :

"Can you put this into different words for me?"